# Adding properties to an object from MongoDB in an array and sending it in the response

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, async-await

I am trying to add the `quoteValue` key-value in an element (an object in this case) of the `users` array using the code below.

When I print out `console.log(users[0])`, it's not showing the value of `quoteValue` for `users[0]`. However, `console.log(users[0].quoteValue)` prints the actual value of `quoteValue`.

I don't understand how it is possible. It would really appreciate your help!

```js
export async function get_client_users(req, res) {
    try {
        let users = await User.find({ role: { $eq: 'client' }, status: { $ne: 'deleted' } }, { name: 1, mobile: 1, email: 1, status: 1, ref_id : 1, _id: 1 });
        for(let i = 0; i < users.length; i += 1) {
            let quotes = await Quote.find({client: users[i]._id});
            const totalQuote = quotes.length;
            let cost = 0;
            for(let i = 0; i < quotes.length; i += 1) {
                cost += quotes[i].total_cost;
            }
            const result = {
                totalQuote: totalQuote,
                quoteValue: cost
            }

            Object.assign(users[i], result);
        }
        return res.status(200).json(users);
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
        return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Technical Error. Please try again later.' });
    };
};
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with `Object.assign(users[i], result);`?  What do you want that array element to look like?  And, is there any reason you don't just do `users[i].totalQuote = totalQuote;` and `users[i].quoteValue = cost;`?

Comment: Where is it that `console.log('user =>', users[0])` doesn't work?   Where did you put that line of code?  It's possible that some properties are configured `enumerable: false` and thus won't show in `console.log(users[0])`, but will show in `console.log(users[0].property)`.  You can test that for sure with `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(users[0])` to see every property that's actually  there regardless of enumerability.

Comment: I am trying to send the ```quoteValue``` and ```totalQuote``` with users in response, how I can send this

Comment: Hi Gaurav, I've edited your post to help others understand your question. Hope it helps!

Comment: I want to attach this key value pair({totalQuote: totalQuote,  quoteValue: cost}) with users and want to send in response

Comment: thanks, @Yves Gurcan

Comment: No problem! I've added my answer below. Does that work for you? If so, please make sure to select it as the accepted answer and upvote it :) Don't hesitate if you have more questions.

Comment: Hi  Gaurav, try below :

users[i].totalQuote = totalQuote;
users[i].quoteValue = cost;

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using destructing (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) if you can to create a new `users` object (called `updatedUsers` in the code below) like so:

```js
export async function get_client_users(req, res) {
    try {
        let users = await User.find({ role: { $eq: 'client' }, status: { $ne: 'deleted' } }, { name: 1, mobile: 1, email: 1, status: 1, ref_id : 1, _id: 1 });
        let updatedUsers = [];
        for(let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
            let quotes = await Quote.find({client: users[i]._id});
            let quoteValue = 0;

            for(let i = 0; i < quotes.length; i++) {
                quoteValue += quotes[i].total_cost;
            }

            updatedUser = {
                ...users[i],
                totalQuote: quotes.length,
                quoteValue
            }
            updatedUsers.push(updatedUser);
        }
        return res.status(200).json(updatedUsers);
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
        return res.status(500).json({ message: 'An error occurred. Please try again later.' });
    };
};
```

I also changed a few things like sending `500` instead of `400` when an error occurs, removed the assignment to the `totalQuote` variable by assigning `quotes.length` directly to `updatedUser.totalQuote`, and also used `i++` instead of `i += 1` in your `for` loops. I would recommend the usage of a linter such as ESLint (https://eslint.org/) or Prettier (https://prettier.io/) to improve the readability of your code.

Additionally, I would suggest to use `map` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to iterate over your `users` object and `reduce` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to get the value of `quoteValue` from the `total_cost` property of your `quotes`, but this is outside the scope of your question.